# "Vector2" не содержит определение для "AngleBetween"

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь посчитать угол между двумя векторами. Есть такой код:

```
public double Calculate_Angel(Vector2 car_vector, Vector2 end_point_vector)
{
    double angle = Vector2.AngleBetween(car_vector, end_point_vector);
    return angle;
}
```

Появляется ошибка:

> Ошибка    CS0117  "Vector2" не содержит определение для "AngleBetween".

Как быть?

Comment: А чего пытаться - в прошлой ветке я дал формулу.

Comment: Что такое `Vector2`? Из какой библиотеки этот тип? В дотнете есть структура [System.Numerics.Vector2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.vector2(v=vs.111).aspx), но у неё нет метода  `AngleBetween`. Такой метод есть в структуре [System.Windows.Vector](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.vector?view=netframework-4.7.2). Обратите внимание, что находятся они в разных сборках.